# El Capitan Unable to Connect to Localhost Server Via External Device in LAN

Tags: macos, webserver, osx-elcapitan

Trying to test a local web app developed on my mac running El Capitan using my iPhone. I'm able to pull up the web app using my internal ip on the actual mac, but when using another device connect to the same network it's not working. This use to work fine on previous versions of osx, but ever since upgrading to El Capitan, this hasn't been working properly.

Any hints or solutions to this problem?
Thanks

Comment: were you able to get this working?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem here on El Capitan. I've done all of the necessary changes as documented here but it still doesn't work: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/. This all used to work under Mavericks and Yosemite with these tweaks but something else has changed under El Capitan that is preventing a connection to a local host via IP...

Comment: It's so sad that nobody can solve this problem, it's a common problem and happens on every el capitan macs.

Comment: Have you tried turning the firewall off?

Comment: I actually am able to load a site running at localhost:3000 from my phone (on the same wifi network). My coworker isn't, however. I'll come back with an answer if we get it.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution ? I'm facing the same issue even with the firewall turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I have a website on my Mac running off MAMP. I couldn't connect to it via IP on another computer. I turned off the firewall on the Mac and could connect by just typing in the IP into the address bar. Mine happened to be `192.168.1.69`. To get the actual website, I did have to include the port number, i.e `192.168.1.69:8888`. Make sure that you are using your private IP, not your public one (should start `192.168.X.X` or `10.X.X.X`). This worked to connect from another computer and from my phone.